# Sql returns Column has "FristName LastName" as 1 string how to order by Lastname?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle. My sql returns a column like this

Name:
John Smith
David Lee
...

If I do Order by Name, it will order by first name. How do I order by Last name? If I do Order by Lastname, Firstname oracle returns invalid identifiers. I tried substr, instr but it doesn't work. I know the sql is tedious but just want the data to quickly fix this issue.

Full SQL:
http://pastebin.com/hYkdHBDM

Comment: What is the actual schema? Is it two columns or a single column that one hopes is in the form of: first name, space, last name?

Comment: Here is the full SQL: 
http://pastebin.com/hYkdHBDM

Comment: Would be better in future to post the SQL in the question and indent by 4 spaces so that stackoverflow does syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in order to sort by LastName, it needs to be one of the columns you return in each of the queries in your Union All. Second, you can greatly simplify your query by using a common-table expression. Third, do not use the comma delimited syntax for Joins (e.g. From TableA, TableB, TableC...). Instead use the ISO Join syntax.

```
With RootQuery As
    (
    Select MeetingID
        , FirstName || ' ' || LastName AS Name
        , LastName
        , CASE WHEN RSVP = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS Yes
        , CASE WHEN RSVP = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS No
        , CASE WHEN RSVP = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS Phone
        , CASE WHEN RSVP = -1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS No_Reply
        , MysteryTable0.Response1
        , MysteryTable1.Response2
        , Note
        , groupname      
      From Attendance A
        Join Allusers As B
            And B.MemberId = A.PersonId
        Join MembershipGroups As M
            And M.MemberId = B.MemberID
        Join    (
                SELECT TD.MEMBERID AS MEM0
                    , Response AS Response1
                FROM TRACKINGDETAILS TD, ALLUSERS U
                Where TD.MEMBERID = U.MEMBERID 
                    And TD.TRACKINGID = 64
                ) MysteryTable0
            On MysteryTable0.Mem0 = B.MemberId

        Join    (
                SELECT TD.MEMBERID AS MEM1
                    , Response AS Response2
                FROM TRACKINGDETAILS TD, ALLUSERS U
                Where TD.MEMBERID = U.MEMBERID 
                    And TD.TRACKINGID = 65
                ) As MysteryTable1
            On MysteryTable1.Mem1 = B.MemberId
        Where Meetingid = :1
        )
Select MeetingId, Name, LastName, Yes, No, Phone, No_Reply
    , Response1, Response2
    , Note, GroupName
From RootQuery
Union All
Select Null, 'Total', LastName, SUM(Yes), SUM(No), SUM(Phone), SUM(No_Reply)
    , TO_CHAR(SUM(Response1))
    , TO_CHAR(SUM(Response2))
    , NULL, Groupname 
From RootQuery
Group By GroupName
Union All 
Select Null, 'Grand Total', LastName, SUM(Yes), SUM(No), SUM(Phone), SUM(No_Reply)
    , TO_CHAR(SUM(Response1))
    , TO_CHAR(SUM(Response2))
    ,NULL, ' '
From RootQuery
Group By ???
Order By GroupName Desc, LastName Asc, Name Asc
```

Btw, the last query will probably have a problem in that it did not have a Group By (which I denoted with `Group By ???`) but you are using aggregate functions.

Comment: Thanks, that's a lot cleaner and might work. I just wanted one row to return on the last query because it is a grandtotal so there is no group by.

Answer (score 2):

You say your SQL "returns a column" in that format.  Do you mean the column is *stored* that way, or that it's stored as two fields and composed into one in the SQL statement?

If stored that way it's difficult to create an algorithm that will reliably determine what part of a multi-part name is the last name part (indeed, this is sometimes down to personal preference of the person owning the name).

If stored in two separate fields you should be able to ORDER BY LastName, FirstName depending on how the SQL is constructed and whether there are any intermediate views between you and the table.  Please post the SQL and table structure.

Comment: It's actually two fields concatenated together As NAME and then UNION ALL 2 times. I have posted the whole sql in my first post. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What Matthew PK said is correct however he failed to mention that INSTR can parse backwards in which case, his "fail" scenario would be resolved.

Here try this:

```
create table test_name (f_name varchar2(20), l_name varchar2(20), full_name varchar2(20));
insert into test_name (f_name, l_name, full_name) values ('John', 'Mellencamp', 'John 2Mellen');
insert into test_name (f_name, l_name, full_name) values ('John', 'Mellencamp', 'John C. 1Mellen');
select f_name, l_name, substr(full_name,instr(full_name,' ',-1,1)) as substr, full_name from test_name order by substr(full_name,instr(full_name,' ',-1,1));
```

Basically the money shot is: **substr(full_name,instr(full_name,' ',-1,1))**

Comment: +1 I didn't realize `INSTR` could parse backwards! Note this is still a problem if people have multi-word last names.

Comment: true, there is no substitute for firstname/lastname columns

Comment: Didn't seem to work. I should have mentioned that there is UNION ALL in the sql. I have posted the whole sql in my first post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you know the field will always be "FirstName LastName" separated by a space you could:

```
ORDER BY RIGHT(Name, INSTR(Name,' '))
```

This is the number of characters, on the right side, starting at the space.

This will fail if any other names are separated by a space like "John Cougar Mellencamp"

Comment: instr can parse backwards, three-name scenario will not fail, see my answer below.